# Apt utilities: Problem with MergeList ... The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened

Tags: debian, apt

When I run an `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` with `apt` or `apt-get`, I get

```
❯ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I also get this error with apt-cache.

What's wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What I tried to do first was move just the file in question,

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye_main_i18n_Translation-en
```

That didn't work though the problem just migrated,

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem parsing dependency 55 of erlang-common-test:amd64=1:23.2.6+dfsg-1
E: Error occurred while processing erlang-common-test (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

At this point I ran

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

And re-ran `apt-get update`. All is good now.